# Push notification from .NET API to VueJS

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js

This description at the moment is all theory, I don't have any code yet. I was hoping to bounce ideas off people.

I have a VueJS app, let's say a To Do app.  It lists all of the things I need to do today.  When I complete a To Do, I check a box in my Vue app and Axios fires of an Http Post to a .NET API end point. Let's say that API method has to do several things, like update several databases, execute a few stored procedures, etc. as in it can take a few seconds to complete.  My Vue app gets a success response and I can then go on to check the next completed item.

If I have several things I've completed it could take several minutes of my day to check, wait, check and wait.  Now I want to check several items or maybe even select all.  I want to submit a list of items to the API, let them queue up and process in the background while I go about other business in the app.  All the while, a panel in the app displays the items still being processed in the background.  As each one completes in the API, a push notification occurs and the UI updates, removing the item from the list.

Does this sound doable? Would I have Vue listening for updates from the API? or would Vue periodically have to poll the API to see what it still has outstanding?  What is the preferred way?  The goal is to free up the user to keep working rather than watch paint dry.

Answer (score 1):

@Connie, I can tell you from experience that it's really possible, with a few tweaks.

The first thing I'd do, is to add all the logic inside `Vuex`.

Making it really simple, the steps would be:
1. Create a `vuex` state called `toDos`, and I'd assume that each `toDo` would be an object containing a format such:

```
toDoModel = {
  id: 1, 
  completed: false
}
```

#### API receives only 1 ID for updating

2. Create a `vuex mutation` for updating this `toDos` state:

```
updateToDo(state, toDoObject) {
  const toDoObjectIndexOnState = state.toDos.findIndex(toDo => 
  toDo.id == toDoObject.id)

  //ToDo not found on state list
  if (toDoObjectIndexOnState == -1) {
    state.toDos.push(toDoObject)
    return
  }

  state.toDos[toDoObjectIndexOnState] = toDoObject
}
```

3. Create a `vuex action` called `updateToDoState`, to perform the Axios call and update state:

```
updateToDoState({commit}, toDoId){
  // Call API on Axios, assuming `data` as the key for returning the toDo with updated info
  response = axios.post(ENDPOINT, toDoId)
  .then({data: toDo} => {
    if (!toDo) return

    // Call mutation
    commit('updateToDo', toDo)
  })
```

4. Make the call on your main Vue Component to call the `updateToDoState` action on each checklist click to update `toDo` state

#### API can receive multiple IDs for updating

(you have two approaches: 
- Have a mutation to change each toDo per time and the action would loop through them all
- Have the action to pass thewhole list and the mutation would take care of updating the store object for each returned Id

*Here my examples assume the fist option*

2. Create a `vuex mutation` for updating this `toDos` state:

```
updateToDo(state, toDoObject) {
  const toDoObjectIndexOnState = state.toDos.findIndex(toDo => 
  toDo.id == toDoObject.id)

  //ToDo not found on state list
  if (toDoObjectIndexOnState == -1) {
    state.toDos.push(toDoObject)
    return
  }

  state.toDos[toDoObjectIndexOnState] = toDoObject
}
```

3. Create a `vuex action` called `updateToDosState`, to perform the Axios call and update state:

```
updateToDosState({commit}, toDosIdsList){
  // Call API on Axios, assuming `data` as the key for returning the toDo with updated info
  response = axios.post(ENDPOINT, toDosIdsList)
  .then({data: toDos} => {
    if (!toDos) return

    // Call mutation
    toDos.forEach(toDo => commit('updateToDo', toDo))
  })
```

4. Make the call on your main Vue Component to call the `updateToDoState` action for batch updating the `toDos` state

In case any part of this logic / code is not 100% clear, just let me know and I can update here!

Comment: So if I pass 100 updates to Vuex you're saying it will queue them all up in the UI and loop through each calling my API 100 times?  Not really what I was looking for.  I'm thinking I would pass all 100 item IDs to the API, let it do the work and as it completes each one, it notifies me so I can update the UI.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko it's all according to your API support.
In order to exemplify, I've added the code for sending multiple `toDos` to the API, so you can see that there's not much of a difference in terms of possibilities